# Web page load time and webmaster

Tags: php, nginx, brotli

I have tried my best to optimize my web pages load time between 20 ms to 30 ms. Every page opens in this time frame but when I see the results on webmaster it says my web pages are taking around 250 ms to 300 ms to download a single page. 
Since we are using PHP and I have also installed brotli (instead of gzip) on my Nginx server.

what else can be wrong ? is it like network congestion or still something wrong with my server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I admire your aim, a load time of 20 ms to 30 ms is just not achievable. 200 - 300 ms is amazing.

When you are measuring, you are probably measuring on a warmed up connection and possibly right besides the data centre. Webmaster (by which I presume you mean Google Search Console?) is not so is likely doing:

1. A DNS lookup (100ms typically)
2. A TCP connection (200ms typically)
3. HTTPS handshake (400ms typically)
4. A request and response for HTML (100ms typically)
5. Any subsequent requests (CSS, JS, Images).

And those “typical” times very much depend on the type and distance of the connection. Again you are probably measuring on a fast PC with a fast internet connection that is already warmed up with steps 1-3 whereas an independent scan like webmasters will not be an may be simulating a slower connection of an average user.

Run your page through https://www.webpagetest.org and ideally share the link to see if there are other opportunities to improve performance.

Comment: May be I’m little confusing. I measured this load time on php page with php code execution time. The code execution time is 30 ms. However, sometimes I see page download time of 100 ms on google webmaster too.

Comment: What is webmasters? What is pho? What is tu? Can you show some screenshots of what you are seeing?

Comment: Its google webmaster and sorry for typo it was PHP.